# Effective ways to extract XML tagged string in Python

Tags: python, xml, mongodb, kml, geojson

My task is to grab a kml file, extract 1 tagged value and send it to Mongo in a geojson.
I'm getting the file as a binary requests object.

```
    doc = requests.get(file).content #returning a XML tree.
```

My question is to find the "best" approach to get the value from the tag. Consider I got multiple sources that needs to be scanned by the minute so even though one run might not take that long, it will build up (being aware that the actual file import will cost more than any extraction process).

The approaches I've tried are BeautifulSoup, slicing and regex. They all work fine, but I would love to get some input on alternatives and/or pros and cons.

```
    def extractsubstring_soup(doc, start):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml-xml')
        return soup.start.string

    def extractsubstring_re(doc, start, stop):
        return re.search('%s(.*)%s' %(start, stop), a).group(1)

    def extractsubstring_slice(doc,start, stop):
        substart = doc.index(start) + len(start)
        subend = doc.index(end)
        return doc[substart:subend]
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you can use http://lxml.de/ and use a XPath query to extract the information you want.

BeautifulSoup is a wrapper around different libraries - you can choose which one - but usually it's for parsing HTML, not XML.